# How to protect joomla from hacking, virus and any other threat?

Tags: joomla-3.x, performance, hack

Hello can any one tell me how to protect joomla from virus and hacking or any other threat?

Comment: Please do some research on this as there are lots of blog posts and tutorials on how to increase security on your Joomla site

Answer (score 0):

**Keeping a joomla website secure**

1. Outdated Joomla Core
2. Extensions
3. Outdated Themes / Templates
4. Weak passwords
5. Outdated Server software
6. Incorrectly configured
       hosting software
7. Incorrectly set permissions
8. Malware